# AWS DynamoDB Table KeySchema RANGE key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to create a DynamoDB table which contains only one order entity with following attributes:

- OrderId
- OrderStatus
- Price

Access patterns I try to achieve:

- Get single order by id
- Filter orders by status

Design in my mind for above access patterns is to create simple primary key consisting of `OrderId` and one local secondary index with composite primary key consisting of `OrderId` and `OrderStatus`. AWS CLI command for achieving this:

```
aws dynamodb create-table \
    --table-name Order \
    --attribute-definitions \
        AttributeName=OrderId,AttributeType=S \
        AttributeName=OrderStatus,AttributeType=S \
    --key-schema \
        AttributeName=OrderId,KeyType=HASH \
    --local-secondary-indexes \
        "[{\"IndexName\": \"OrderStatusIndex\",
        \"KeySchema\":[{\"AttributeName\": \"OrderId\",\"KeyType\":\"HASH\"},
                      {\"AttributeName\":\"OrderStatus\",\"KeyType\":\"RANGE\"}],
        \"Projection\":{\"ProjectionType\":\"INCLUDE\", \"NonKeyAttributes\":[\"Price\"]}}]" \
    --provisioned-throughput \
        ReadCapacityUnits=1,WriteCapacityUnits=1 \
    --table-class STANDARD
```

When running this command, I get:

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTable
> operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Table KeySchema
> does not have a range key, which is required when specifying a
> LocalSecondaryIndex

How can get rid of this error while sticking to my design? Or if it is not possible how should I design my table in this case?

Comment: For the 2nd access pattern, I think you want a GSI (not LSI) with hash=OrderStatus and range=whatever is useful to you (probably OrderId, so the query results are ordered within status by order ID). You can then query the GSI for all orders with status X.

Comment: it does make sense, thanks! I think I'd rather use price for range key, since I want to see it as well when querying by order status

Comment: In that case, make sure you project the orderId into the index (or just project all attributes, assuming it's just the 3 shown), unless you don't actually need it in the query response.

Comment: You don't need to project OrderId, as the GSI will include the keys to the table automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a Local Secondary index is that it has the same Partition Key as the table , but a difference range key.

In order to have a partition key other than what the table uses, you'll need a Global Secondary Index.

Comment: Is it a violation to have a local secondary index with different range key? And what is your proposed solution?

Comment: an LSI should have a different range key than the table does (assuming the table even has a range key)